# С++. Алгоритм Евклида(Нахождение НОД(Найбольшего общего делителя)), вроде алгоритм правильный, а выдает самое первое введенное

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int NSD (int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int n, a, b, i;
    int c=0;
    cout<<"Vvedite kakoe budet kol-vo chisel:";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Vvedite chislo nomer #1: ";
    cin>>a;
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vvedite chislo nomer #"<<i+2<<": ";
        cin>>b;
        int NSD (int a, int b);
    }
    cout<<"NSD="<<a;
}


int NSD (int a, int b)
{
while (a!=b)
if (a>b) a-=b;
else b-=a;
return a;
}
```

**Суть работы программы:**

*Введите с клавиатуры N целых чисел. Найти самый общий делитель этих чисел. Для вычисления наибольшего общего делителя двух чисел НОД(a,b) по алгоритму Евклида создайте функцию. Функция должна иметь 2 параметра – два целых числа и возвращать целое число – самый общий делитель этих чисел.*

Comment: У вас функция не вызывается, а объявляется лишний раз.

Comment: В цикле написать `a = NSD(a, b);` вместо `int NSD (int a, int b);`.

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с несущественной мелочи — наибольший общий делитель обычно называют по-английски greatest common divisor, а стандартная функция в С++ для его вычисления — `gcd`. Я бы еще понял `NOD`, но `NSD`? просто запутывающее название.

Далее,

```
int NSD (int a, int b);
```

просто объявление ("где-то будет определена такая функция"), но никак не ее вызов. Понимаете разницу? Вы уже сделали объявление перед функцией `main`, больше таковое не nребуется. А вызов должен иметь вид

```
a = NSD(a,b);
```

А последнее — сама ваша функция реализована плохо. Представьте, что вам дали ряд из чисел

```
3 5 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 ...
```

Что получится? При первом вызове вы получите 1, а потом начнете каждый раз выполнять по миллиарду вычитаний. Никакого смысла в этом нет, следует использовать получение остатка от деления, например, так:

```
int NSD(int a, int b)
{
    while(a && b) if (a < b) b %= a; else a %= b;
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>a;
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    cout<<"Vvedite chislo nomer #"<<i+2<<": ";
    cin>>b;
    int NSD (int a, int b);
}
cout<<"NSD="<<a;
```

а где у вас результат функции то, который вы выводить будете?

```
int res = NSD(a, b);
cout<<"NSD="<<a;
```